# Jquery .css is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

https://jsbin.com/feyoronene/edit?html,css,js,console,output

I'm trying to set the body to my window's height and weight, but I tried a lot of times to do it. I don't know what's wrong, I did the console.log(width + ' ' + height) and I got the datas, but I can't add that property to css.
What am I doing wrong?

```js
var width = $(document).width();
var height = $(document).height();
$('body').css('background-size', width + 'px' + ' ' + height + 'px');
```

```css
body {
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you inspect the `body` after running your code? It's working just fine.

Comment: ^ working fine for me as well, it's just that setting the `backround-size` whithout an actual background doesn't give you much to see.

Comment: what are you trying to make the size as the css your using `background-size`is for a background image, nothing else? The code just has a blank page?

Comment: Please post your code here, not just as a jsbin link.

Comment: @adeneo `background-size`*

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - My tipyng is horrieblbe ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not just do...

```
var width = $(document).width();
var height = $(document).height();
$('body').width(width).height(height);
```

If you want the body to be the same size as the window size.

If you want the background size to be the same size as the window, then your current code is working. If you want your code to run everytime the user changes the windows size you can wrap this function around your code:

```
$(window).resize(function () { 
    //code goes here 
});
```

Comment: this works perfectly. Also, I did a newbie mistake, typing href instead of src at script syntax so it basically didn't loaded my script.